# Getting compass mix-ins to work with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, compass-sass, sass

I'm trying to get scss gradients to work from [colorzilla's handy gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). I get an error when adding that scss code to assets/stylesheets/header.css.scss:

> Undefined mixin 'filter-gradient'.   (in
>   /Users/me/code/app/assets/stylesheets/header.css.scss)

So I add the `@import "compass/css3/images";` to my header.css.scss file:

```
@import "compass/css3/images";

header address {
  background-color: #c9de96;
  @include filter-gradient(#c9de96, #398235, vertical);
  $experimental-support-for-svg: true;
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(top,  #c9de96 0%,#8ab66b 44%,#398235 100%));
}
```

Now I get this error:

> File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/images. Load
>   path:
>   Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/me/code/app/assets/stylesheets/header.css.scss)
>   (in /Users/me/code/app/assets/stylesheets/header.css.scss)

I had to add compass-rails to my Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

How do I get these linear gradients to work with scss and rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So annoyed to have wasted time on this. I just needed to restart the web server!

Comment: Exactly my problem. Thank you for following up with your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer just in case someone runs into a similar problem like I did using compass 0.12.2. In your .scss file include this:

```
@import "compass";
```